# What to do when you've posted an incorrect answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, answers

I thought I had an answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37266/reload-xserver-xorg-input-mouse). My answer was accepted and got 2 up votes, but then I realized that it doesn't actually work. I updated the answer with a semi-retraction, but I don't know what else I should do.

Is there a way to remove its accepted status?

Is there a way to promote the question again, so it can be answered correctly? (I'd really like to know the answer!)

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, only the asker can unaccept an answer. In this case since the answer no longer answers the question, I converted it to a comment, so the question is considered to have no answer now and will show up on the [unanswered list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/unanswered). You can further promote a question by putting a [bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it, although you don't have [enough reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to do that yet

Answer (score 4):

In case you wondered (like I did), but did not try: you cannot delete your answer once it is accepted, but it can be deleted through moderator intervention or by being flagged, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79578/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-deleted). (Some selections after flagging bring out moderator attention as well).

Your question here on meta is valid and had the result you wanted, but I don't think we want to  have a question here for each accepted answer which has similar problems. So the right thing to do in these cases is **flag your own answer for moderator attention**, and select 'other' with an explanation. You can of course include a proposed course of action for the moderator there as well (complete remove, only unaccept, convert to comment, etc.).